# How to Make a rolling percentile evaluated from beginning to each element (through the end) in an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, percentile

Here is some code that I've written to create a rolling percentile evaluated at each row in the array.  This code works fine, but it is SLOW!  It takes 10 seconds to run 8,000 rows, and my computer is not slow.  Does anybody know how to make this run faster?  Caveats (All of these calculations need to be in memory, so no range references are allowed).  I ran the percentile formula as a check from a fixed point, dragged down, and it is faster than this over the same data.  Any tips?

Thank you so much in advance! :)

```
Dim Current_MACD_Percentile() As Double

  ReDim Preserve Current_MACD_Percentile(1 To UBound(MoveAvg5, 1), 1 To 1)


            Dim Current_MACD_Percentile_Arr() As Double
            Dim Current_MACD_Percentile_Elm_Arr As Variant

                    For x = 1 To UBound(MoveAvg5)

                            For w = 1 To x
                            ReDim Preserve Current_MACD_Percentile_Arr(1 To 1, 1 To x)
                            Current_MACD_Percentile_Arr(1, x) = MACD_SD_Pct(x, 1)
                            Next w

                    With Application.WorksheetFunction
                    Current_MACD_Percentile(x, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(.Index(Current_MACD_Percentile_Arr, 1, 0), 0.985)
                    End With

                    Next x

    With Worksheets("Program Requirements")
    .Range(.Cells(5 + m - 1, 19), .Cells(Last_Row, 19)).Value = Current_MACD_Percentile
    End With
```

Comment: FYI, the code prior to this executes in about .25 seconds, so I know specifically that this loop is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the loop-within-a-loop.  You mention in the question that you have 8000 rows, so I assume that UBound(MoveArg5) is around 8000.  If so, the inner loop is running 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + .... + 8000 = (8000 * 8001) / 2 = 32 million times!  And you're redim'ing your array with each loop.

Plus, the inner loop isn't doing anything.  You use "For w = 1 to x", but then inside the loop you don't reference w, so the inner loop is just repeating things needlessly.

Also, you have created two dimensional arrays, but then only seem to be using a single dimension (the other dimension is always set to 1) -- you could simplify by using one dimensional arrays.

Honestly, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here.  But if this code "works" but is just slow, then remove the "For w=..." loop completely, leaving the inner part alone in the "For x = " loop.  That should speed things up tremendously.

Or, explain which array contains your "raw" data.

EDIT:

Sorry for the delay, busy at work.

So if your data is in MACD_SD_Pct(x,1) here's an option:

```
Dim TempArr() as Double, R as integer, AnswerArr() as Double

Redim AnswerArr(UBound(MACD_SD_PCT,1))

For R=1 to UBound(MACD_SD_Pct,1)
  Redim Preserve TempArr(R)
  TempArr(R)=MACD_SD_Pct(R,1)
  AnswerArr(R)=Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(TempArr,0.985)
Next R
```

Since you haven't posted any data I'm not certain, but this worked on 400 made up data points on a worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That loop is the best way I know how to accomplish the following:  Line 1 will be the 98.5 percentile of line 1, Line 2 will be the 98.5 percentile of array elements 1 and 2, Line 3 will be the 98.5 percentile of array elements 1 and 2 and 3, etc.  All the way until it hits around 8000 rows in MoveAvg5.  I know why it's running so slow, I just don't know how else to accomplish this calculation.  The percentile measurement must only be from the current element position to the Lower bound.  Do you know a better way to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to add, the raw data is being extracted from MACD_SD_Pct(x, 1).